# Is there a sequence of random variables such that $\mathbb{P} (\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} X_{n} = 0) = 0.5$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

As in subject, is there a sequence of random variables $\left \{ X_{n} \right \}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ $\mathbb{P} (\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} X_{n} = 0) = 0.5$?

I say yes, because take $A=\left \{-1, 0 \right \}$ and $X_{n}(\omega)=\omega^{n}$.

Then $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} X_{n}(0) = 0$ and the limit of $X_{n}(-1)$ not exists.

So $\mathbb{P}(\left \{ \omega\in A: \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} X_n =0\right \}) = \mathbb{P}(\left \{ 0 \right \}) = 0.5 $

But I have a feeling that I am wrong. What about Kolmogorov's 0-1 theorem? What about independence of $X_n$?

Comment: Are you requiring the sequence $(X_n)$ to be independent or are you not? If you are, the answer is "no", for the reason you say. If you are not, the answer is "yes", as tons of examples show.

Comment: I was interested if there exists such a sequence if we do not know anything about dependence.

Comment: Then see third sentence of my comment.

Comment: To see that without the independence assumption the answer is trivial, consider the elementary sequence: $P(X_1 = 0) = 0.5, P(X_1 = 1) = 0.5$, then $X_n = X_1\forall n>1$ (a.s.). Then clearly $P(\lim_{n \to \infty}X_n = 0) = P(X_1 = 0) = 0.5$ as desired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example is correct. But, as you correctly state, due to Kolmogoroff, your variables cannot be independent. And, of course, they aren't, as can for example be seen via $$ P (X_{n+1}=0 \mid X_n = 0) = 1 \ne \frac 12 = P (X_{n+1}=0)$$

Comment: You must've refer $1\neq 1/2 = P(X_{n+1}=0)$